# App closes after phoneCallTask is shown Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, phone-call

On mainpage I call several methods. First methods says some text and then I open CallDialog. This is the code for dialog:

```
   private void CallDialog()
    {
        PhoneCallTask phone = new PhoneCallTask();
        phone.PhoneNumber = "911";
        phone.Show();

    }
```

In MainPage loaded event handler I call :

```
        await Speak("Do you want me to call?");
        CallDialog();
        await Speak("ba bla");
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
        timer.Start();
```

And first line goes off well, and then phone call dialog pops up..The following method does not execute.. if i remove all the folowing methods it works all well.. and if i put

```
MessageBox.Show("something");
```

after phone call task it shows up before phone call dialog..

Comment: Yes this launches a different application, putting yours in the foreground (or tombstoning it, if resources are low).  Are you expecting your app would still be running when another app is run>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get that correctly, however when you call `phone.Show()` it basically jumps out of your app and executes phone call with system application so that is why your code is not executed afterwards.

In other words it is not your app that makes calls (not possible) it is your app telling the system who to call.

Those tasks are called launchers and if you want to continue with your code, you must wait until user finishes action which is in your case phone call.

Comment: yes, this is all good, but if i dont have any methods after phone call task, and i close task, it goes back to app and shows main page without doing anything.. if i have await Speak() methods it crashes... i tried to catch error and it said: The text assoicated with this error code could not be found
[9.9.2014 20:20:57] Nejc Lovrenčič: a speech operation was aborted by a system call for example fast app switching or an incoming phone call

Comment: So it probably stops your method. I would try to set some bool value before executing CallDialog() and then add code to OnNavigatedTo event with if condition and bool. True value would mean that call was executed and you could do different stuff than when launching app in normal way.